# How to deal with a TokenExpiredError: jwt expired?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jwt

I have a project with NodeJS with jwt for managing user authentication. After a period of time, my app stops working and my server prints the following:

```
return done(new TokenExpiredError('jwt expired', new Date(payload.exp * 1000)));
                    ^
TokenExpiredError: jwt expired
```

Now, the person who was working in this project before me had this code for managing the tokens:

```
static generateToken(username, type, id) {
 return jwt.sign(
   {
      username,
      type,
      id
   },
   API_SECRET,
   {
       expiresIn: '7d'
   }
 );
}

static generateRefreshToken(username, type, id) {
 return jwt.sign(
   {
     username,
     type,
     id
   },
   API_SECRET_REFRESH,
   {
     expiresIn: '30d'
   }
 );
}
```

My guess is that the issue is the `expiresIn: '7d'` (since I'm quite new with jwt). I also know what we can omit the `expiresIn` field to make the token not expire at all. My question is: Is it safe to omit said field or there's another way to tackle this kind of error message? Since every time that message pops up, I have th delete the entire browsing history of my browser (or run my project in incognito mode) in order for it to start working again.

Comment: If you set the expiration time to 1 week, do not use the token for 1 week. Use it less than a week and get a new token before the old token expires. For example, make the browser send out a request to exchange for a new token at the sixth day. This is not different than the normal concept of session and cookies.

Accordingly, on the server side, create a restful API named /token/extend which will return a new token if given a valid token.
 Read [this](https://gist.github.com/soulmachine/b368ce7292ddd7f91c15accccc02b8df)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not create a token that does not expire. So, you should keep the `expiresIn` config.

That being said, you don't have to use `refresh token` strategy. There are a lot of ways to handle this. For example, you can do the following:

1. Create `/check-token` endpoint that will check if the current token is still valid.
2. Create token when user logs in. Token will be valid for 7 days for example.
3. Each time user opens your application call the `/check-token` endpoint. If current token is not valid, logout the user. If current token is valid, generate new token that will be valid for another 7 days and continue to authenticate the user with new token.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is one of the most common problems, it is possible to solve it with a refresh token, what this function does is that when the token expires, a request is made from the front to obtain a new one, here is a link with an example of implementation in node js:

Link: https://www.bezkoder.com/jwt-refresh-token-node-js/